# I use AccessibilityEvent.getSource() get TextView.Can I do something to change the TextView's text?

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

This is my code.In my custom `AccessibilityService`,I get all `TextView` by the method,`onAccessibilityEvent`.And then I want to mark the text.

```
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {

    AccessibilityNodeInfo source = event.getSource();
        if (source == null) {
            return;
        }

    for (int i = 0; i < source.getChildCount(); i++) {
         AccessibilityNodeInfo node = source.getChild(i);
         if (TEXTVIEW.equals(node.getClassName())) {
         if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
          Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
                    arguments.putCharSequence(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_ARGUMENT_SET_TEXT_CHARSEQUENCE,
                            node.getText().toString()+1);//just want to mark
                    node.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_SET_TEXT, arguments);
                }

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: What I do has no effect

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Be more clear!  If you want to change announcement then set exact text accessibility announcement on view

Comment: I want to change other app's TextView.Can I make it?

Comment: I dont think you can modify announcement of other apps view.

Answer (score 1):

This bit of code works fine for me!

```
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent e) {

    if (e.getSource() == null) return;

    if (e.getSource().getClassName().equals(EditText.class.getName())) {

        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putCharSequence(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_ARGUMENT_SET_TEXT_CHARSEQUENCE,
                "android");
        e.getSource().performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_SET_TEXT, arguments);

    } 
}
```

And happily places the text "android" into the editable text container!  AH, now, if you want to change the text of a TextView, now, this is an illegal thing to try and do.  The text of a TextView is a readonly property.  You can't edit it.  An accessibility node info is an accessibility services representation of a rendered view.  You can't ask the App to change the text of a TextView.  This has MASSIVE security implications.  Oh, so you have a service that tells everyone that the Password field is the Username field and vice versa?  Isn't that handy?  Basically, you can only edit the text of a view that makes sense to be Editable.

That being said, you can tell the user that the text is whatever you want to tell them it is, when you provide feedback.  Not that I would use an accessibility service that spoke "kitten" for every view in the hierarchy... but, your use case/what you want to accomplish is not clear.  If you would provide another question that asks "This is what I want to accomplish..." instead of "this is what I tried, why doesn't it work?" I would happily help.